# Yii - remove url rule dynamically

Tags: php, yii

Is there any possible way to remove a url rule from the urlManager on the go?

I know I can add a rule via `urlManager->addRules()`, but how do I delete them?

Thanks.

EDIT:

My aim is to generate the rules dynamically based on the subdomain. 
For example, a subdomain of certain type would have a rule `<catalog>/<brand>/<product>` leading to a certain product, while the other would have a different rule. Also, the subdomains are also dynamic, meaning that I can't create any static conditions.

Answer (score 2):

You have all rules here:

```
Yii::app()->urlManager->rules;
```

That's an associative array, you can easily loop through it and manipulate it.

Answer (score 0):

It would be great, if you could provide more details about why you need such behavior.

In common, you can extend default `CUrlManager` class and add needed functions. After that you can specify this new, let's say, `CustomUrlManager` in `config.php` as implementation for your `urlManager`.

But again - what problem do you try to solve?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there wasn't a clear way to solve this problem.

The inner rules array `_rules` is declared private, and there are no methods for working with it apart from `addRules()`. This method, however, only allows you to append the processed rules to the start/end of the `_rules` array. You won't be able to delete the rules you've added, too.

The solution I came up with is bad practice, but there was no other way of working around my issue (that I know of).

1. Declare a method *inside* `CUrlManager`

   ```
   protected function clearInnerRules() {
         $this->_rules = array(); // clears the inner rules array
   }
   ```
2. In the child class `UrlManager` that is used as the manager for the Yii app, declare:

   ```
   public function reprocessRules() {
        Yii::app()->cache->delete(self::CACHE_KEY); // remove anything rule-connected from cache
        $this->clearInnerRules();
        $this->processRules();
   }
   ```
3. Using the `onBeginRequest` event, add rules to the placeholders in the array:

   ```
   // code
   Yii::app()->urlManager->rules['rulePlaceholder'] = $newRule;
   Yii::app()->urlManager->reprocessRules();
   // code
   ```

Done. Now I can easily delete the rules or replace them at any moment (provided, this moment is before the request). Sometimes you just gotta do what you gotta do, I guess.